# HightCharts : area range and spline in the same graph issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Based on "Area range and line" demo, I created following example code :

```
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });

            var opts = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'gfx',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Archived data'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    crosshairs: true,
                    shared: true
                },
series:[
{"name":"cpuload (1 minute)", "type":"spline",
"data":[
    [1364688000000,0.319545],
    [1364742000000,0.195],
    [1364752800000,0.144],
    [1364756400000,0.266],
    [1364767200000,0.245],
    [1364770800000,0.184286],
    [1364774400000,0.1],
    [1364832000000,0.33],
    [1364857200000,0.16],
    [1364896800000,0.249091]
],
"zIndex":1,
},
{ name: "Range",
"type":"arearange",
"data":[
    [1364688000000,0.02,0.55],
    [1364742000000,0.1,0.29],
    [1364752800000,0.08,0.22],
    [1364756400000,0.19,0.33],
    [1364767200000,0.11,0.38],
    [1364770800000,0.08,0.41],
    [1364774400000,0.1,0.1],
    [1364832000000,0.33,0.33],
    [1364857200000,0.09,0.23],
    [1364896800000,0.31,0.31]
],
lineWidth: 0,
"linkedTo":":previous",
"zIndex":0,
"fillOpacity":0.3
}
]
            }
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(opts);
```

But no graph is created. No error message, but no graphics :(
If I change "type":"arearange", to "type":"spline", I got a graphic, with 2 line (as expected).
And I stuck on that for 2 days without no luck :(

Any tip, idea code ?

Thanks

Laurent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using highcharts-more.js?

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLDeq/12/

Comment: yep, you got it. I missed this point and lost lot of time for that :(.  THANKS A LOT.